# Kubernetes cronjobs with error status history

Tags: python, kubernetes

I have a simple pod with 2 containers. One with python code and the other is just for logging purposes. We have failedJobsHistoryLimit and successfulJobsHistoryLimit set in the yaml file, so we can view logs of both failed and succeeded pods. So it looks like this

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: test
spec:
  schedule: "*/30 * * * *"
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 10
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 2
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      ttlSecondsAfterFinished: 172800
      backoffLimit: 0
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
              ....
```

The problem is, if there is a python error in the first container then the pod's status is Error. Then the limits do not apply and the pod is removed and you are unable to view the logs anymore. I cannot find such a thing in the docs, but my dream parameter would be something like errorJobsHistoryLimit. Is there any way how to achieve this? We are interested in the logs only, we do not care about restarting etc.

Comment: it would be best have a proper logging solution in place, potentially involving fleunt-bit or fluentd and something like elasticsearch. Apart from this, I don't really understand what your problem is. Perhaps you can describe it in more detail or provide a reproducible example.

Comment: I agree with the proper logging solution, but unfortunately we are not there yet. So if a pod succeeds, then there is no problem running `kubectl logs my-pod` to view the logs, the successful pods are also listed in `kubectl get pods`. However, pod with `Error` status doesn't show up in `kubectl get pods`, therefore I cannot get to its logs. Well, all of this happens during night, so I assume it shows up there for a brief moment, but I'd like to check the logs in the morning, but the pod is not listed there anymore.